# C# Debugger text visualiser output aligned with Console output in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to get the Debugger text visualizer to show output that is aligned nicely to match the console output in VS2019?  Or even some other type of visualizer type if appropriate?  The `DataTable` object has a nice debug visualizer but what if you're working with objects that aren't DataTables?

The example below gives an example.  We are inspecting the `printer` object.

The console output for `printer` is nicely spaced as expected:

[image]

But if you inspect the object in debug mode, the visualizer output isn't aligned right. It looks like spaces have less horizontal distance than alphanumeric characters.

[image]

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace visualiser
{
        [DebuggerDisplay("{" + nameof(DebuggerDisplay) + ",nq}")]
        public class Printer
        {
            private string[] columns = {"price", "quantity"};
            private double[] values = {12.10, 2};

            private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

            public override string ToString() => StackedStrings();

            private string Top()
            {
                const int padForPeriod = 1;
                const int msDigits = 3;
                var corner = string.Empty.PadRight(
                    19 + padForPeriod + msDigits, ' ') + "|" + 
                             columns[0].PadLeft(15) + "|" + 
                             columns[1].PadLeft(15) + "|";
                return corner;
            }

            private string PrintRow()
            {
                var str = "2018-10-16 17:00:02.115|";
                str = str + values[0].ToString().PadLeft(15) + "|" + values[1].ToString().PadLeft(15) + "|";
                return str;
            }

            public string StackedStrings()
            {

                var str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, PrintRow());
                str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Top(), str);
                return str;
            }


        }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var printer = new Printer();
            Console.WriteLine(printer);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/proportional_font.html

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I'd say it's more a hack/work around than a good solution, as it makes all the text in visual studio look quirky .... if MSFT can fix this issue without requiring this hack it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the provided comment, a quick search including the key words C# visualizer *fixed pitch text* reveals this may be a specific issue with Visual Studio 2019.  This issue and one work around is discussed here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/653607/visual-studio-debugger-text-visualizer-font-is-not.html

Currently one work around is to go to
Tools -> Options -> Select the  Environment tab -> Fonts and Colours -> In the drop down select Environment, and choose a fixed pitch font.

[image]